# Html.DropDownListFor() - How to set default selected value for a strongly typed view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Using ASP.NET MVC 3, I have been struggling to set the selected value for dropdown using the help Html.DropDownListFor() function for a strongly typed view.

The code for the models look like this:

```
public class ResourceView
{
   ...
   public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
   public string DisplayName { get; private set; }      
   public string Code { get; private set; }    
   public override string ToString() {  return DisplayName;  }
}
```

and within the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language, 
  new SelectList(ViewBag.AllPossibleLanguages, 
    "Code", "DisplayName", Model.Language.Code))
```

There are a few workarounds, such as using

```
@Html.DropDownList("LanguageCode", 
   new SelectList(ViewBag.PossibleLanguages,
      "Code", "DisplayName", Model.Language.Code))
```

and curiously enough, the code above **won't** work if the first parameter is set as "Language", same as the name of the property in the model.

I can also do like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language, 
  new SelectList(ViewBag.AllPossibleLanguages))
```

which will work as well with the appropriate selected value, however only the ToString() value of the Language class will be displayed and the actual language code that i want in the option tags won't be set, which is not surprising as there is nothing identify that the Code field should be used as the value attribute.

I can also solve this using a jquery event handler that selects the appropriate value afterwards. However I am curious as to **why** this doesn't work as intended and would like to solve it properly if possible.

Comment: TL;DR: It's the fourth parameter in `new SelectList(items, dataValueField, dataTextField, selectedValue)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument for `@Html.DropDownListFor` is the property of your model the selected value will be bound to on Post. When you say `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language)` the default binder won't able to figure which property in your Language class it needs to bind the selected value which in the case of dropdown list will always be a single string or integer. For the same reason `@Html.DropDownList("LanguageCode")` works.

You can always extended the default model binder if you would like to change the behavior.

**Edit:**

You could try, which I believe should solve your problem in this case.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model.Language.Code, new SelectList(ViewBag.AllPossibleLanguages))
```

Comment: this seems to work:
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language.Code, new SelectList(ViewBag.PossibleLanguages, "Code", "DisplayName"))  
I thought it was only possible to bind to direct properties of a model, not to the properties of its relation as well. there is still one problem however It seems to create a form parameter name called "Language.Code" automatically, and I'm not sure how to bind to form parameters with a "." in them inside the controller?

Comment: Solved the above problem by taking a Language as a parameter. Apparently the model binder will take care of the period inside the parameter name.